# Android Async Task code structure

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am currently trying to make an AsyncTask that downloads a file in android. It's at a preliminary state but my code gets drowned in try catch statementes that I autocomple using eclipse's suggestions.

Here is the code from a single function that creates and writes to a file:

```
 public void CreateFolder(View view) throws Exception{

         File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Dit+/Files");
         folder.mkdirs();
         folder.toString();         
         File file = new File(folder, "test.txt"); 
         String url="http://cgi.di.uoa.gr/~std10108/a.txt";

         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(url);
         fw.write(a);
         fw.close();
    }
```

while when I transfer this block to the async task it turns to this:

```
private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params){

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Dit+/Files");
            folder.mkdirs();
            folder.toString();
            String a=params[0];
            File file = new File(folder, "test.txt");

            FileWriter fw = null;
            try {
                fw = new FileWriter(file);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                fw.write(a);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                fw.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return null;

        }
```

I know that for the time using the async task is useless but I want to familiarize first with the concept of async tasks rather than using it as it should. Actually the url string is the source of the file I want to to download but I just want to make an example for now.

So my question is: Is there any way to write the async task without these try-catch statements because it makes the code unreadable and ugly.

Calling the function CreateFolder() in the doInBackground() function of the async task would be a good implementation?

Comment: You can put all three calls in one try-catch block, no need to separate them.

Comment: yes, just use one try catch, that would make code easy readable. for an example you can see a sample async task code here: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342189/push-data-to-android-app/20342529#20342529)

Answer (score 1):

use one try catch:

```
    private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Dit+/Files");
        folder.mkdirs();
        folder.toString();
        String a=params[0];
        File file = new File(folder, "test.txt");

        FileWriter fw = null;
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(file);
            fw.write(a);       
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            return null;

    }
```

Comment: Thx I feel pretty dumb now. It seems so simple!